# Accessing an instance of a class from a different block of code

Tags: c#, methods, datagridview

I have a project with a `dataset` with `datable` within this called "Tool". this is bound to a `datagridview`.

This `datatable` has info on tools, and qty's associated with each tool as well. this list populates the `datagridview`.

Is there a way to have a `button_click` event that changes qty in the `datatable`, and update the `datagridview`? I have other textboxes bound to the table. that update as the selection is changed in the table. but to sum this up I want to change qty(value in a column) for the selected row, when user clicks a button.

below is main program. not listed, is my button_click event, as it is still pretty much empty. i'm just not too sure where to begin.

**Main**

```
public void mainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var loadscreen = new SplashScreen();
        loadscreen.Show();


        //json file holding all data to be parsed.
        string myDynamicJSON = File.ReadAllText(@"testLibrary.json");
        //the data
        ToolJson ToolData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ToolJson>(myDynamicJSON);

        //DataTable with something in it, do the binding
        BindingSource SBind = new BindingSource();
        SBind.DataSource = tooldataSet.Tables["Tool"];
        


        //looks into File finds json fields, and assign them to variables to be used in C# to 
        //create the rows.
        foreach (var datum in ToolData.datum)
        {
            string description = datum.Description;
            string vendor = datum.Vendor;
            double cost = datum.Cost;
            string serial = datum.ProductLink;
            string employee = datum.employee;
            string location = datum.location;
            bool returntool = datum.returnTool;
            int onHand = datum.onHandQty;
            int stockQty = datum.stockQty;
            int orderQty = ToolData.Order(datum.stockQty, datum.onHandQty); //stockQty - 
            //onHand = orderQty, if value is less than 0, set the value of orderQty to 0.
            string toolType = datum.Type;
            double diameter = datum.Geometry.Dc;
            double OAL = datum.Geometry.Oal;
            string productID = datum.ProductId;
            


            //Populate the DataTable with rows of data
            DataRow dr = tooldataSet.Tool.NewRow();

            // Fill the values
            dr["Description"] = description;
            dr["Vendor"] = vendor;
            dr["Cost"] = cost;
            dr["Serial #"] = serial;
            dr["Employee"] = employee;
            dr["Location"] = location;
            dr["OnHand"] = onHand;
            dr["StockQty"] =stockQty;
            dr["OrderQty"] = orderQty;
            dr["Return"] = returntool;
            dr["Diameter"] = diameter;
            dr["OAL"] = OAL;
            dr["Type"] = toolType;
            dr["Product Id"] = productID;
            


            //once all data is added to the row, add the row, and loop untill all data is 
             loaded.
            tooldataSet.Tool.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        //bind our dataset.table to the gridview
        toolDataGridView.DataSource = SBind;


        //hide splashscreen once Gridview has loaded the data
        loadscreen.Hide();



    }
```

Comment: What is the need for a button? Couldn’t the user simply “change” the `qty` value in the grid?

Comment: basically if im using this software i would walk up to the computer, scan a barcode in a text field, which will find the correct row in the list, and then click a "pull" to remove 1 from a count. or "return" to add 1 to the count. i dont want people manually typing numbers in. mainly this is because the button makes things a more controlled event, where if they start editing the grid directly they could do all kinds of things and then possibly break my code more easily. id rather leave grid readonly

Comment: OK. If the user clicks the “pull” button then what is the problem with decrementing the count in the grid or table? If the grid has a `DataSource` it is recommended to “change” the value in the `DataSource`, however you can do this in the grid if you must. I am not following what it is that you cannot do. The user clicks the button, your code grabs the grids selected row and increments or decrements the counter for that row.

Comment: I'm just asking if there is a way to change the values in the datatable from outside of the main part of code

Comment: Not sure what you mean by…”_... outside of the main part of code”_ … ? … _”I'm just asking if there is a way to change the values in the datatable”_ … it would be a useless table if you could not change the values in the cells. If the grid has a `DataTable` as a `DataSource`… then you could use the grids `SelectedRows` collection to “grab” the currently selected row in the grid. From that row you can either “change” the value in the grid row itself or the grids `DataSource` table. It will work if you change either one and it should “update” both.

Comment: i do want to change the values in the cells. but in a controlled environment. i will give what you are saying a go. but it doesnt seem like it was that simple for me when i looked into this

Comment: _“controlled environment”_ … ? … so you currently have no control over the environment your code is running in? And YES it is as simple as I described. I mean no disrespect but… It appears YOU are making it complicated.

Comment: No doubt I am, and no disrespect received. I'm just trying to wrap my head around this. yes controlled environment. I know I will have a multitude of mistakes and exceptions that can and will happen in this software. I don't see how its a negative that I'm expecting to have these issues and thus control how much input is given to reduce the amount of possible issues. these issues still would need addressed, but I can't see the harm in reducing risk.

Comment: I am not sure if I agree with your approach. Users are almost guaranteed to do things wrong and if you don’t look for those wrong things, then it makes YOU look bad because your code crashes. On the other hand, if you disable a control to minimize the user mistakes, then your code loses functionality. Example a grid… users know what grids are and in most grids they can “edit” the cells… but not your grid. Again, this reflects back to YOU as it may not crash but it has “limited” functionality.

Comment: Many controls like text boxes and grids have a plethora of events specifically made JUST for checking what the user is doing and your code can capture those events. I will not deny that trying to capture all the dumb things users will do is next to impossible, however, learning how to capture and fix obvious and common mistakes the user WILL make will go a long way in making your code more functional and as a goal… user friendly.

Comment: thank you very much for your input. You may not know full context of the project, but in general your point stands. however, there is literally about 2 things I want the average user to do with this software.. 1 pull a tool from inventory, and 2 return a tool to the inventory. aside from that alot of the features im adding are just to view data for personal use., to see what trends we are making with tooling here at our shop, and to see what improvements we can make to our tooling needs to keep costs down. anyways thank you for the help. all your points are noted.

Comment: _"You may not know full context of the project, "_ ... and "who's" fault is that?

Comment: _”your comments this entire time have not once tried to answer the actual question.”_ … this is not true. My 2nd and 3rd comments suggest you change the value in the data table or the grid. … and I still stand by those suggestions. Please forgive me, I meant no disrespect; it is not my intention to “wow” you with anything. My goal was to try and help you solve your problem. Obviously I have failed miserably at this and apologize for that. I will bow out and leave this to wiser minds. Good Luck.